# How to customize legend labels in flex

Tags: apache-flex, charts, legend

I am developing a chart in the flex and i want to have customized legend labels. Customized in the sense that if i bind certain data source to the chart then it will show x axis labels into the legends by default.

So for example,

> By default it shows legends like this : 2011, 2012, 2013
>
> How i want to make them display is : 2011 ( 30% ), 2012 ( 40%), 2013 ( 12.45%) and
> so on.

I googled my problem but was not able to get the exact solution what i was looking for. Can anyone please tell how can i achieve this thing?

Comment: What is the data format, to which you are binding your Chart control ?

Comment: Refer to this link.. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_formatting_13.html, see the displayName property

Comment: @ChetanSachdev : i am using amf data format and i have already reffered this link. It doesn't help me. I hope you are clear with the question. I need to customize the labels that are given in the legend. In my case i cannot directly add series into the chart via mxml. It is coming from the actionscript.

Comment: Can you paste a sample of your dataprovider and a screenshot to give more clarity..

Comment: I would look at the Legend class, in particular there is a private method `addLegendItem()` at line 6081 (WTF, 6000+ lines for this "simple" object!?). In this method it is receiving **some chart object** from the chart and getting the label. If you run this through the debugger, I'm guessing you can find some way to get the percentage and add it to the label (on line 6087). I'd do this, but you haven't provided any code (ie: what kind of chart, etc) so I'm not going to bother guessing at what that "some chart object" is and what your data looks like.

Comment: By the way, this is the same direction that Chetan Sachdev was pointing you to. You you might have better luck by overriding the functionality in the `Legend` class, b/c it will have access to the chart data ... though the above method is working on one data item at a time, so calculating the percentage of the total may be a little more work.

Comment: @SunilD. : It's a pie chart and i am having so much data to be displayed in it. So that i was thinking if i can customize legend labels like 2011 (0.03%), 2012 ( 10%) and so on, i can display my all data in a meaningful way. Regarding the code i am also clue less where to start that's why i posted this question. Thanks for the addLegendItem() suggestion. I'll look into it if it can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is not possible to do so.